# Passing jQuery Selectors to a function Server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, selector

I want to pass jQuery selectors to a Javascript function Server side.

Here is my Javascript function :

```
     function DisableOperations(Selector) {
        alert(Selector);

        $(Selector).parent().find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

And it is my server side code :

```
string Selectors = "a:contains('test1') a:contains('test2')";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "DisplayMessage", string.Format("DisableOperations('{0}');", Selectors), true)
```

This code doesn't work (Javascript function doesn't call) because variable selectors contains this (').

And when I write

```
string Selectors = "a:contains(test1) a:contains(test2)";
```

jQuery selector doesn't because argument in 'contains' function in selector should be between ' and '.

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `var sel = eval(Selector);` ?
first just try escaping your single quotes. "a:contains(\'test1\') a:contains(\'test2\')"

Comment: first just try escaping your single quotes. "a:contains(\'test1\') a:contains(\'test2\')"

Comment: @shaahin: You probably need two ``\`` to escape the quotes. Try `string Selectors = "a:contains(\\'test1\\') a:contains(\\'test2\\')";`